# How to send a reminder using java mail and servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, outlook, jakarta-mail

Is it possible to send a reminder using java mail like outlook?.

I just want to send a mail to user and after about one week if the user is not reacted to that than the reminder has to be send after a week or so.

How to do this in java mail or is there any other way or mechanism to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a scheduler to trigger the event for a mail send.

Have a look at [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/community) its a good scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

You can send an iCalendar [VEVENT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1) attachment. Outlook should recognize this as a reminder.